# how to get instagram user profile to basic scopes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, instagram-api, react-native-instagram-login

I was authorized to **Baisc Scope** on the **Instagram Developer's Web** to implement a **react-native Instagram social login**. However, to obtain the user's profile (name, e-mail, etc.) live mode was also approved.
But now `'Invailed scope filed(s): public_content'` error appears.

I can't find it even if I look it up on the Internet. So I've tried very little JavaScript script:

```
<InstagramLogin
   ref={(ref: React.RefObject<InstagramLogin>) => this.instaRef = ref}
   clientId='MyClientId'
   redirectUrl="MyRedirectUrl"
   scopes={['basic', 'public_content']}
   onLoginSuccess={(token: any, results: any) => 
                  this.instagramLogin(token, results)}
   onLoginFailure={(data: any) => 
                  Alert.alert('Error', `${data}`, [{text : "Ok"}])
/>
```

I think the user profile should be transferred to response data at the result value of `onLoginSuccess`.

Comment: what the package you using?

Comment: I used react-native-instagram-login module

Comment: @권희준, Same problem here. Are you got solution?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati Yes, I fix this problem Can I help you?

Comment: Yes, How's you get user firstName, lastName and email after get token?

Comment: Um... As far as I remember, Edit React-Native-instagram-login module, There is a code in the file that is retrieved using API, and I remember modifying the API's endpoint. If this doesn't work, let me know how to communicate, and I'll let you know right away.

Comment: @SunilPrajapati Are You Fixed? More Comment?

Comment: @권희준, Yes, Fixed